# How do I properly use Nuxt emit?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vue-composition-api

I am trying to develop `vue.js` application, but recently faced a problem using `emit` function. The thing is that event successfully sends at child component, but it never appears at parent component.

Here is the code of parent component:

```
<template>
  <SearchBar placeholder="text3" />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
// ... some imports here

export default defineComponent({
  components: { Header, Users, SearchBar, AccountPage },
  setup() {
    // trying to listen an event here, but program never achieve this method
    function search(value: string): void {
      alert(value)
    }

    return { search }
  },
})
</script>
```

Code of child component:

```
<template>
  <div class="search-bar-wrapper">
    <input :placeholder="placeholder" type="text" class="input" @input="onInputAction($event.target.value)" />
    <img :src="searchImage" alt="" class="search-img" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// ... imports

export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    placeholder: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      default: '',
    },
  },
  emits: ['search'],
  setup(_, { emit }) {
    function onInputAction(value) {
      emit('search', value)
    }

    return {
      onInputAction,
      searchImage,
    }
  },
})
</script>
```

So the `onInputAction` function works, but never calls a `search` method from parent component. Also I need to mention, that I am using `Nuxt v2` and `composition API`. Help would be very appreciated

Answer (score 0):

`@search` property missing at `<SearchBar placeholder="text3" />` component
Working version of parent component:

```
<template>
  <SearchBar placeholder="text3" @search="search"/>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
// ... some imports here

export default defineComponent({
  components: { Header, Users, SearchBar, AccountPage },
  setup() {
    // trying to listen an event here, but program never achieve this method
    function search(value: string): void {
      alert(value)
    }

    return { search }
  },
})
</script>
```